# Select Id, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess didn't understand relationship name on sObject Event

Tags: soql, event, userrecordaccess

On `Account` I can run a query like so:

```
Select Id, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess FROM Account
```

and this would give me the information about user's access to the record in a single query.

However, if I run the same against `Event` I get an error

```
SELECT Id, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess FROM Event
```

> Didn't understand relationship 'UserRecordAccess' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Is there any way to query it in one go?

Comment: `Select Id, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess FROM Account` - this shouldn't be possible - where's the doc that supports this?

Comment: @cropredy no idea re: docs, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late to the party, but certain system objects do not have the UserRecordAccess relationship. Task and Event are a couple of them.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my first post basically says. The question was not `is it supported`. The question was `Is there any way to query it in one go?`